# modifying CURLOPT_RESOLVE in libcurl

Tags: c, libcurl

Please consider this code snippet, I need guidance on altering `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` in `libcurl`

```
//snip
#include <curl/curl.h>
#include "myown_dns_client.h"

//just curly things
CURL *hnd;
struct MemoryStruct {
  char *memory;
  size_t size;
};
CURLcode res;
struct curl_slist *slist1 = NULL;
struct MemoryStruct chunk;
//just curly things


int main(){
    //snip//
    return 0;
}

void setup_curl(){
        curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
        chunk.memory = NULL;
        chunk.size = 0;

        hnd = curl_easy_init();
        curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);

        if (get_address_from_lookup() ==0){
                // we have updated slist which looks like dns.google.com:443:172.217.14.206
                slist1 = curl_slist_append(NULL, slist);
                curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_RESOLVE,slist1);
                printf(" ** %d Updating slist to %s\n", getpid(), slist);
        }

}
```

Later in a thread `update_slist`, if dns.google.com starts to resolve towards a new adddress, say, `216.58.193.78`, I'd like to alter the `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` option. (So we start sending requests to this new address.)

```
void *update_slist(void *vargp){
        curl_slist_free_all(slist1);
        struct curl_slist *slist1 = NULL;
        // slist now contains "dns.google.com:443:216.58.193.78"
        slist1 = curl_slist_append(NULL, slist);
       curl_easy_setopt(hnd, CURLOPT_RESOLVE,slist1);
}
```

Not sure whether this is the correct approach to alter `CURLOPT_RESOLVE`. Despite the new `slist1` I  see in `netstat -pant` that I am still going to the initial address, not the new one.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**Edit 1**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

CURL *curl;
struct curl_slist *host = NULL;
struct curl_slist *temp = NULL;
CURLcode res;
char text[8192];
FILE *popener;

void show_netstat();

int main(){

    char url[] = "https://dns.google.com/resolve?name=www.hulu.com&type=1";

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    host = curl_slist_append(NULL, "dns.google.com:443:172.217.14.206");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, host);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    show_netstat();
        if(res != CURLE_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
      }


    puts("\nNEXT!");
    temp = curl_slist_append(NULL, "dns.google.com:443:216.58.193.78");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, temp);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    show_netstat();
        if(res != CURLE_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
      }


    puts("\nDONE!");
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(host);

    return 0;
}


void show_netstat(){
    popener = popen("netstat -pant 2>/dev/null |grep 443","r");
    fgets(text,8192, popener);
    printf("\n----------------- ------------------- ---------------");
    printf("\n%s", text);
    printf("----------------- ------------------- ---------------\n");
    fclose(popener);
}
```

**ngrep o/p**

```
T 192.168.1.10:53872 -> 172.217.14.206:443 [AP]
T 172.217.14.206:443 -> 192.168.1.10:53872 [A]
T 172.217.14.206:443 -> 192.168.1.10:53872 [A]
T 172.217.14.206:443 -> 192.168.1.10:53872 [AP]
T 192.168.1.10:53872 -> 172.217.14.206:443 [AP]
T 172.217.14.206:443 -> 192.168.1.10:53872 [AP]
T 192.168.1.10:53872 -> 172.217.14.206:443 [AP]
T 172.217.14.206:443 -> 192.168.1.10:53872 [AP]
T 172.217.14.206:443 -> 192.168.1.10:53872 [AP]
T 192.168.1.10:53872 -> 172.217.14.206:443 [AP]
T 172.217.14.206:443 -> 192.168.1.10:53872 [AP]
```

**Edit 2**

Niether does this work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

CURL *curl;
struct curl_slist *host = NULL;
CURLcode res;


int main(){

    char url[] = "https://dns.google.com/resolve?name=www.hulu.com&type=1";
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    host = curl_slist_append(NULL, "dns.google.com:443:172.217.14.206");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, host);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
      }

    puts("\nNEXT!");
    sleep(3);

        host = curl_slist_append(host, "-dns.google.com:443");
        host = curl_slist_append(host, "dns.google.com:443:216.58.193.78");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, host);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
      }


    puts("\nDONE!");
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_slist_free_all(host);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your second edit, note that your you keep appending to the *same* list after the sleep(3), so the list then contains one resolve-add one resolve-remove and then another resolve-add ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed override a previously set `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` entry by setting a new one for the exact same host + port, or you can clear a previously set one by passing in a line like `-[host]:[port]` (ie starting with a dash and without a trailing `:[address]`).

Just setting the value to NULL means there's no new entry to pass in, which will make the curl handle keep the data already pre-populated since before.

This is documented in the [CURLOPT_RESOLVE man page](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_RESOLVE.html).

### A note on connection reuse

libcurl will try to reuse previously used connections as far as possible unless you tell it otherwise. If you do a second request to the same host name that you previously used, that connection will then be reused and the new `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` setup might then not be used or checked.

If you want to make it really sure that your second request actually uses the updated address, you must make sure that the second transfer doesn't reuse the connection still held alive from the first transfer. You can achieve this either by setting `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE` on the first connection or by setting `CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT` on the second.

Comment: Could you please look at **Edit 1** above? I still don't see any traffic going to the 2nd address.  I feel i am close, but not 100% there yet.